# Error:Runtime() has private aaccess in java.lang.runtime

Tags: java, button, runtime, exec, processbuilder

I am trying to make this action: when I click the button "search" command prompt windows is open.

I tried to use ProcessBuilder, no errors appeared, but it didn't work. Could you help me please?

```
package sys.tool;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
//Создаем поля
public class MainWindow extends JFrame{
    private JLabel lcn = new JLabel("Enter computer name:");
    private JTextField icn = new JTextField("", 5);
    private JButton search = new JButton("Search");
    private JLabel lun = new JLabel("Enter user name:");
    private  JTextField iun = new JTextField("", 5);
    private JLabel empty = new JLabel("");


    public MainWindow (){
        super("SysAdminTool");
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 700 , 90);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);

        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2 , 1, 1));
        container.add(lcn);
        container.add(icn);

        container.add(lun);
        container.add(iun);

        container.add(empty);
        search.addActionListener(new SearchEventListener());
        container.add(search);
    }

    class  SearchEventListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

           Runtime rt = new Runtime();
           rt.exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C","start"}); \\Here a make an event for button, to open cmd when I click the button.





        }
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Runtime.html):

> Every Java application has a single instance of class Runtime that allows the application to interface with the environment in which the application is running. The current runtime can be obtained from the getRuntime method.
>
> An application cannot create its own instance of this class.

So instead of `new Runtime()` try `Runtime.getRuntime()`

Comment: Thank you for reply, I am started to study java, and my skill is small. As I understood correct, if I want to use runtime - I have to write <code>Runtime.getRuntime</code>   in all cases, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Java doesn't allow you to create a new Runtime object so you have to use the getRuntime() method to get the one Java automatically creates.

Comment: Ok, it was funny mistake. Thank you very much for assistance.